# Prototype img src swap doesnt work in Firefox?

Tags: javascript, firefox, prototype

I was using the following code in a function activated onClick to swap an image (id=bigPicture).  It worked great (in Chrome) and I moved on.  I go into Firefox later to check and was flabbergasted when it didn't work as expected.  The src does not change.  Now, I am a noob when it comes to prototype so maybe this isn't the correct way to go about things.  What do you folks think?

```
$(bigPicture).src = filename;
```

Comment: That should work fine in Firefox.  Are you sure there were no other errors reported?  Can you duplicate the behavior in a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) test?

Comment: @Pointy it should work if bigPicture was a reference to a string.  See Shads answer below.  Quote marks are an easy thing to overlook

Comment: Yes I assumed that you meant "bigPicture" was a variable holding a reference to a string, because otherwise it is not possible that it would work properly in Chrome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

String quote the element id~

```
$('bigPicture').src=filename;
```

Comment: well butter my bisquit, you seem to be right!  I'm kind of mad that Crome let tis work

Comment: **Chrome's Apparent Logic:** Random constant? hmmm let me see if I have an element with that id....

Comment: But but ... there's no possible way that Chrome could do the "right" thing there, since in that case it would definitely be the wrong thing ...

Comment: Chrome automatically creates global variables for each statically defined HTML element - using "id" attribute as the name of the variable.  It also appears to work in Firefox 4.0, but FF will spew a warning out to the Firebug console not to do this.  FF will also create a var for each element on the document object as well.  So "window.bigPicture", "document.bigPicture", and "bigPicture" have differently likelihoods of working across different browsers.

Comment: Isn't the correct syntax above suppose to be:

$("#bigPicture").src = filename;

Comment: At least within Prototype you just use the id~